# Node Server not Accessible Using PM2 on Windows Server

Tags: node.js, pm2, windows-server

Using pm2 on Windows Server the Node server is not accessible but if I restart using `pm2 restart server.js` it does become accessible.

I am using pm2-windows-startup to start the server on system boot.

If I run `pm2 status` after reboot it shows it is running but the service is not available until I run `pm2 restart server.js`.

Not really a Windows expert... I've already allowed exceptions in the firewall, etc. Any idea on what else could be the problem?

Comment: Did you find a reason for your issue? 
I have a similar situation, my app creates files on the windows server after reboot, pm2 logs shows there was a permissions issue reading/writing to a dir. In my case I actually had to give modify permissions on that directory to the windows user/group assigned to node.js. The reason it was working when fired from the CLI was that I was in as admin.

Comment: @Ultradiv No, I never solved the problem. After reboot, pm2 will show it's running but it is not available. 'pm2 restart <whatever-service>' works to solve it but it's irritating that this has to be done every reboot.

Comment: have you checked the pm2 logs? It may help us find a solution